# How to ORDER BY in each GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

i have data like this:

| Name | Class | Pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nam | A | 5 |
| Hung | B | 1 |
| Tran | A | 6 |
| Hoang | A | 1 |
| Bao | B | 4 |

so now i want to make query on this table to group all students by class, in each class, studen will be sorted descending by index.
My expected table be like:

| Name | Class | Pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tran | A | 6 |
| Nam | A | 5 |
| Hoang | A | 1 |
| Bao | B | 4 |
| Hung | B | 1 |

Here is my query

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    from
    (
        SELECT 'Nam' as name, "A" as class, 5 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Hung' as name, "B" as class, 1 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Tran' as name, "A" as class, 6 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Hoang' as name, "A" as class, 1 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Bao' as name, "B" as class, 4 as pos
    )t0
    ORDER BY pos DESC
)t1 
GROUP BY name, class
```

But the output look so different:

| Name | Class | Pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nam | A | 5 |
| Hung | B | 1 |
| Tran | A | 6 |
| Hoang | A | 1 |
| Bao | B | 4 |

if i filter only class A, it look like

| Name | Class | Pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hoang | A | 1 |
| Tran | A | 6 |
| Nam | A | 5 |

only correct for class B:

| Name | Class | Pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bao | B | 4 |
| Hung | B | 1 |

Look like the order in sub-query can not be kept after group by.
My finally query will look like:

```sql
SELECT class as Class, COLLECT_LIST(name) as Name FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    from
    (
        SELECT 'Nam' as name, "A" as class, 5 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Hung' as name, "B" as class, 1 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Tran' as name, "A" as class, 6 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Hoang' as name, "A" as class, 1 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Bao' as name, "B" as class, 4 as pos
    )t0
    ORDER BY pos DESC
)t1 
GROUP BY class
```

If `GROUP BY` can keep order base on pos in sub-query then `COLLECT_LIST` will produce expected result like this:

| Class | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | [Tran, Nam,Hoang] |
| B | [Bao,Hung] |

How to group and order internal in each group?

Thanks

Comment: You've tagged with 3 different (and incompatible) databases.  What is your actual database?

Comment: I'm a little lost.  MySQL doesn't have `collect_list()` so your code won't run on MySQL.  Please clarify.

Comment: yes, `collect_list()` is my custom function for mysql, it just simply collect all values of each `groupby` and store as array, no magic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY`, in the middle of your query is useless. It should be put after the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    from
    (
        SELECT 'Nam' as name, 'A' as class, 5 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Hung' as name, 'B' as class, 1 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Tran' as name, 'A' as class, 6 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Hoang' as name, 'A' as class, 1 as pos
        UNION 
        SELECT 'Bao' as name, 'B' as class, 4 as pos
    )t0
)t1 
WHERE class='A'
GROUP BY name, class
ORDER BY pos DESC;
```

output:

```
+-------+-------+-----+
| name  | class | pos |
+-------+-------+-----+
| Tran  | A     |   6 |
| Nam   | A     |   5 |
| Hoang | A     |   1 |
+-------+-------+-----+
```

An explanation about `ORDER BY` can be found here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

> A "table" (and subquery in the FROM clause too) is - according to the
> SQL standard - an unordered set of rows. Rows in a table (or in a
> subquery in the FROM clause) do not come in any specific order.

EDIT: If you have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled (which is the default in MySQL8.0+), you will get an error like this:

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
> clause and contains nonaggregated column 't1.pos' which is not
> functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

This is because grouping is done on `name` and `class` so SQL does not know which value to use for `pos` in that group. Should it that the highest value? of the lowest value? (or some other value...).

I did not notice (not enough coffee...). A re-write with this problems solved looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   name, 
   class, 
   min(pos) as pos 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'Nam' as name, "A" as class, 5 as pos
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Hung' as name, "B" as class, 1 as pos
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Tran' as name, "A" as class, 6 as pos
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Hoang' as name, "A" as class, 1 as pos
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Bao' as name, "B" as class, 4 as pos
)t1 
WHERE class="A"
GROUP BY name, class
ORDER BY pos DESC;
```

Comment: yes, i intend to do that but then mysql ask to put `pos` to `GROUP BY` as well. then the output is not correct anymore. i just want to use pos to order, not group by it

Comment: Please add the info where mysql ask to put `pos` to `group by` to your question. I tested above query, and it does not group by `pos`.

Comment: yep, when i run your query, it throw this: `FAILED: MySQL[1,8] Semantic analysis exception - column reference t1.pos should appear in GROUP BY key`

Comment: ah, I see, the full erorr message is: "ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 't1.pos' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".   I will do an edit.....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question which was actually asked.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you just need a two level sort first by class, then by index:

```sql
SELECT Class, GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Pos DESC) AS Name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Class
ORDER BY Class;
```

Comment: actually i want to group by class, then aggregate list of student name follow the descending order of pos. i can collect list of student as array inside sql by custom function
example:

Comment: -------|class | names|

Comment: -------|A    |   [Tran, Nam, Hoang]|

Comment: @unclebob: that's not the output you asked for in your question.

Comment: @unclebob I have updated my answer.  For future reference, please avoid dramatically changing your question after others have already answered.

Comment: thanks, i've just updated the final result that somebody ask me to explain more clear the issue. sorry for that

Comment: but the group_concat is awesome. i can use SPLIT(GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Pos DESC) AS Name) to convert it back to ARRAY type. thanks a lot. it works

Comment: could you explain why you use order by `Class`?